# Modifing fields form order of CustomUser model

Tags: python, django

I created a `customUser` model so that the default `User` is overwritten.

This is my `customUser` model:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
  helper = FormHelper()
  class Meta(UserCreationForm):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('first_name', 'username', 'email', 'last_name', 'organization', 'location', 'postcode', 'phone', 'agree_conditions')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
  class Meta(UserChangeForm):
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name','organization', 'location', 'postcode', 'phone', 'agree_conditions')
```

Everything works perfectly however I am not able to change the order of the "User default" fields.

I know how to re-order the form fields, I can simply change the order in the `fields = (a, b, c)`. For example if I want "c" to appear before "a" and "b" in the form, I can do: `fields = (c, a, b)`.

**HOWVER I want to move up the password and password confirmation**

but I do not know how to do so because I do know know their name in the User default model.

Ideally I want this:

```
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'PASSWORD_WHICH_I_DONT_KNOW_THE_NAME', 'CONFIRMPASSWORD_WHICH_I_DONT_KNOW_THE_NAME' 'first_name', 'last_name','organization', 'location', 'postcode', 'phone', 'agree_conditions')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was silly of me.

I inspected the HTML of the form and found out that:

- the "PASSWORD_WHICH_I_DONT_KNOW_THE_NAME" is named by default: password1
- The "CONFIRMPASSWORD_WHICH_I_DONT_KNOW_THE_NAME" is named by default: password2

So it will be:

```
fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2' 'first_name', 'last_name','organization', 'location', 'postcode', 'phone', 'agree_conditions')
```